# Upload image to firebase storage

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to upload an image taken from the camera to the firebase storage, an message dialog appears but it keeps on charging and no images are uploaded to the storage.
Also I'd like to know, how can I get back the image sent from a specific user? should I give the image the user name to the image so I can get it back with his name?

```
public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 10;
    private LocationService service;
    private Button uploadbtn;
    private ImageView imgSpecimentPhoto;
    private ImageView imgSpecimentPhoto2;
    private ImageView imgSpecimentPhoto3;
    private StorageReference storage;
    private ProgressDialog mProgress;
    Uri photoURI;
    String mCurrentPhotoPath;
    private File createImageFile() throws IOException{
        //Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss" ).format( new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_.";
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir( Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES );
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,
                ".jpg",
                storageDir
        );
        mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }
    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent(){
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent (MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if(takePictureIntent.resolveActivity( getPackageManager())!= null){
            //Create the file where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try{
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            }catch (IOException ex){
                System.out.println("error taking the pic");
            }
            //Continue only if the file was successfull
            if(photoFile != null){
                photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile( this, "com.example.android.fileprovider",photoFile);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult( takePictureIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST );
            }
        }
    }


    private View currentView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile );
        service = new LocationService(this);
        uploadbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.upload);
        storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        mProgress = new ProgressDialog( this );

        //get access to the image view
        imgSpecimentPhoto = findViewById(R.id.camerabtn);
        imgSpecimentPhoto2 = findViewById(R.id.camerabtn5 );
        imgSpecimentPhoto3 = findViewById(R.id.camerabtn6);


        uploadbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mProgress.setMessage("Uploading...");
                mProgress.show();
                dispatchTakePictureIntent();


                    }
                } );



            }


    public void checkPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                ) {//Can add more as per requirement

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                    123);
        }
    }

    public void btnTakePhotoClicked(View v) {
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
        System.out.println("first");
        currentView= v;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        photoURI = data.getData();


        //did the user chose okay
        if(requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

            //we are hearing back grom the camera
            Bitmap cameraImage = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get( "data" );
            //now we have the image
            ImageView cur = (ImageView) currentView;
            cur.setImageBitmap( cameraImage );
            if (cur.getId() == imgSpecimentPhoto.getId()) {
                imgSpecimentPhoto2.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
            }
            if (cur.getId() == imgSpecimentPhoto2.getId()) {
                imgSpecimentPhoto3.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );

            StorageReference filepath = storage.child("Photos").child( photoURI.getLastPathSegment());
            filepath.putFile( photoURI).addOnSuccessListener( new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Upload Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mProgress.dismiss();

                }
            } ).addOnFailureListener( new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText( ProfileActivity.this, "Upload Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } );



                                }

            }


        }}
```

Comment: I have written a service in android, which compresses and uploads image to firebase and broadcasts on progress, you can check it on https://github.com/ashishkumar468/FirebaseImageUpload

Comment: https://github.com/AtifAbbAsi19/Firebase-Helper/tree/master/app/src/main/java/inc/droidflick/firebasetutorial/firebasenetwork check this helper class for firebase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when upload image on Firebase used below code ...

```
   bearImage.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    bearImage.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bitmap = bearImage.getDrawingCache();
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();

    // Upload it to our reference
    UploadTask uploadTask = bearRef.putBytes(data);
    buttonDownload.setEnabled(false);
    uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            // Handle unsuccessful uploads
            progressDialog.dismiss();

            Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Upload failed: " + exception.getMessage());
        }
    }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            // taskSnapshot.getMetadata() contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.
            Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
            progressDialog.dismiss();

            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Download Url: " + downloadUrl);
            buttonDownload.setEnabled(true);
        }
    });
```

remove code for not need in above code..

Comment: bearImage is ImageView control object.

Comment: it gives me this error  Cannot upload to getRoot. You should upload to a storage location such as .getReference('image.png').putFile...

Comment: you make folder in firebase storage like below code ..  FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        StorageReference rootRef = storage.getReference();
        StorageReference bearRef = rootRef.child("images/bear.jpg"); 
In Firebase storage create images folder then upload bear.jpg image.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. It gives me the same error

Comment: If you want to then provide my full demo for upload and download image from firebase storage .

Comment: you can refer this link ::https://androidjson.com/retrieve-stored-images-firebase-storage/

Comment: okay I think I found the problem, it doesn't find the directory. How do I locate the directory where to upload the image?

Answer (score 0):

About getting the image back with the username,
I would upload the photo in the storage with the following **path**:

```
// storage/photos/users/userID/photoName
StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage
                                   .getInstanace().getReference
                                   .child("photos/users/" + user_id +  "/photoName");
```

And then I would create a **photos node** in data base where I would add the **userID** and then the picture. Something like that:
In this specific case I am storing the user's profile photo into the database. ProfilePhoto model is just the profile image url.

```
ProfilePhoto profilePhoto = new ProfilePhoto(profile_img_url);
myRef.child("photos").child(user_id).child("photoName").setValue(profile_img_url);
```

By this way, when I want some user's photo I just get the link from database specifing the userID.